# Install python package

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, python-module, python-idle

Can we install python packages in IDLE (Python Shell)?
I know how to do it in windows cammand prompt. But I want to install packages in python shell. 
If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

```
from subprocess import Popen
package_name = input("Enter package name to install")
Popen(["pip","install",package_name])
```

Using Popen will be effectively the same as running the command in a terminal or command prompt, but without another window opening. It will all take place in your shell.

Comment: Thanks for providing code which might help solve the problem, but generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem.